# Adsorbable Organic Halides (AOXs) in bleach residue

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, halides, absorption

I have a question regarding using household bleach, and wonder if someone knowledgeable can help, please?

I have used household bleach (sodium hypochlorite, sodium hydroxide, coco alkyldimethyl, amines, N-oxides, non-ionic surfactants) to bleach mold that had formed in my bathroom on the tiles. I probably used too much, undiluted, and the result has been large patches of salt residue which have formed on the bath tub.  I use the bath tub to shower, and to be honest, I hadn't removed some of the residue for a while, but when I have tried, it is quite stubborn.

I believe the breakdown of bleach results in harmless compounds, but I have read that a small percentage consists of adsorbable organic halides. My concern is, are these harmful, if they get in shower/bath water? Do they stick to the salt residue, or are they washed away quickly? The salt residue does not come off easily when rinsing, so are there no longer AOXs present, or are they potentially leaching into the water from the residue over time? I sometimes have cuts/dry skin so wonder about the possibility of absorption, and any risk this may pose.

Many thanks.